# Tough combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

The Morse code is a method to transmit letters and digits with dashes and dots, for example, to send a message by turning a flashlight on and off.

How many different code words can be made using three dots and three dashes in each word?

Answer (score 2):

This is just permutations with repetitions. We have six objects, two sets of which are indistinguishable, and we need to find the total number of unique permutations. We can use the formula $$\frac{n!}{q!p!}$$ where $q$ and $p$ are the number of each repeated object. In our case, there are two repeated objects, the dots and dashes, and there are 3 of each. So the answer is $$\frac{6!}{3!*3!} = 20$$

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slightly different idea on ImHereSomtimes's answer, but you have six objects in some order, three belonging to one group (dots) and three belonging to the other group (dashes). A code word of this form is uniquely determined by deciding which of the objects are dots, and which are dashes. If you just pick three to be dots, you can automatically say the others are dashes and be done. The number of ways to pick $3$ objects from $6$ is ${6\choose 3}=20$.